# Cmake and vcpkg - find the correct library name

Tags: cmake, vcpkg

I have troubles finding out the right "library target name" to be used in a cmake file, for packages installed using vcpkg.

In example, I installed the `gtest` package using `vcpkg install gtest`. My sample cmake file looks like:

```
#CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(example)
add_executable(main main.cpp)
find_package(gtest REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(main gtest) # here, "gtest" is not the right name!
```

Running `cmake`, a solution for Visual Studio is generated, but after running `cmake --build .`, I get the error:

```
../use-cmake-vcpkg\main.cpp(1): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'gtest/gtest.h': No such file or directory ..
```

---

Turns out the line: `target_link_libraries(main gtest)` isn't correct, and I need to use another "name" to include/link the gtest package.

Is there a way (using cmake or vcpkg) to find out what is the correct target name to be used? (for gtest in this case, but also for any other pacakage?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When use `find_package(XXX)`, it can work in two modes: *MODULE* and *CONFIG*. And resulted variables and targets of this call **depend on the mode**.

If `FindXXX.cmake` file exists (and can be found), the *MODULE* mode is used and given file is processed. Otherwise, if the package is shipped with `XXXConfig.cmake` file, *CONFIG* mode is used and given file is processed. If none of this file exists, CMake emits an error (if called with *REQUIRED* keyword) or a warning (without *REQUIRED* keyword).

In case of `gtest` package, CMake is shipped with `FindXXX.cmake` script, so this script is processed in *MODULE* mode. You may find description of this script in the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/module/FindGTest.html), which tells that you need to use `GTest::GTest` target for link with gtest:

```
target_link_libraries(main GTest::GTest)
```

Comment: or `GTest::Main` if you're building an executable

Answer (score 0):

Not all packages provide a CMake library definition. If you're lucky, then `vcpkg install` will show you the name:

```
$ ./vcpkg install openssl

The package openssl is compatible with built-in CMake targets:

    find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)
    target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE OpenSSL::SSL OpenSSL::Crypto)
```

This will work even if you've already installed the package, so you can use it anytime to query the package name.

On the other hand, if `vcpkg install <pkg>` doesn't say anything about CMake, then you need to include it manually in your CMake file, by finding the `include` path and the `library` files.

Here is an example of such a case, here for the `live555` library:

```
# Use one of the headers to locate the include location
find_path(LIVE555_INCLUDE_DIR liveMedia.hh)

# Find the libraries
find_library(LIVE555_LIBRARY1 liveMedia)
find_library(LIVE555_LIBRARY2 groupsock)
find_library(LIVE555_LIBRARY3 BasicUsageEnvironment)
find_library(LIVE555_LIBRARY4 UsageEnvironment)

add_executable(rtsp testRTSPClient.cpp)
target_include_directories(rtsp PRIVATE ${LIVE555_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(rtsp PRIVATE ${LIVE555_LIBRARY1} ${LIVE555_LIBRARY2} ${LIVE555_LIBRARY3} ${LIVE555_LIBRARY4})
```